# ReportViewer programmatically populate it with a dataset

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have a access database which I'm connecting to however i would like to refresh the report view with data dependent on the user options.

How would i do this?

For example i have a dataset i made called dsDealer and a report.rdlc file

i would like to update the objectdatasource with new data.

Any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you did to put data in the dataset....do it again with the new data.

On the ReportViewer object, call DataBind().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx